# How to center div tag in the middle of the page

Tags: html, css

I need to place the div class icons in the middle and on the image section2, I don't know whether the margin-top:-17% really placed the div on the image or not.

```
    <img style="padding-top:5%; width:100%;"src="img/image-section2.png">
        <div class="icons" style="position: relative; z-index: 2;margin-top:-17%;display:block;width:100%">
            <div style="float:left">
                <img style="width:25%"src="img/Project-icon.png">
                <h3 style="margin-left:-15%;width:200px;text-align:left;font-family:Raleway;font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;text-transform:uppercase;color:#FFFFFF;">complete Project</h3>
                <h1 style="margin-left:5%;width:200px;text-align:left;font-family:Arial;font-size:20px;text-transform:uppercase;color:#FFFFFF;">120</h1>
            </div>
            <div style="float:left">
                <img style="width:25%;"src="img/cup-of-coffee.png">
                <h3 style="margin-left:-15%;width:200px;text-align:left;font-family:Raleway;font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;text-transform:uppercase;color:#FFFFFF;">cups of coffee</h3>
                <h1 style="margin-left:5%;width:200px;text-align:left;font-family:Arial;font-size:20px;text-transform:uppercase;color:#FFFFFF;">570</h1>
            </div>
            <div style="float:left">
                <img style="width:25%;"src="img/award-icon.png">
                <h3 style="margin-left:-15%;width:200px;text-align:left;font-family:Raleway;font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;text-transform:uppercase;color:#FFFFFF;">Award Winners</h3>
                <h1 style="margin-left:5%;width:200px;text-align:left;font-family:Arial;font-size:20px;text-transform:uppercase;color:#FFFFFF;">682</h1>
            </div>
            <div style="float:left">
                <img style="width:25%;"src="img/customer.png">
                <h3 style="margin-left:-15%;width:200px;text-align:left;font-family:Raleway;font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;text-transform:uppercase;color:#FFFFFF;">happy customers</h3>
                <h1 style="margin-left:5%;width:200px;text-align:left;font-family:Arial;font-size:20px;text-transform:uppercase;color:#FFFFFF;">900</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: you want the image to be a background of the page?

Comment: @repzero maybe that will explain more http://imgh.us/Capture_553.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of applying inline-styling for each tag. Use a style tag and include one style for all your class /ids (to avoid redundancy).

Add a background image too the parent container. Instead of using a spearate imag tag

Give each sub-container a class named "sub_container"

Remove their float property. Display them as table-cell. Add a white-space : nowrap property.

in the main container simply add padding top and buttom of equal size. This will make the items look as if they were centered in the page

Snippet below (to be placed in resizable window)

```css
div {
  color: black;
}

#container {
  background: url("https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTomMW37agCBOu64_RK6Kn8kQyN9937Upm5XZXRPkwCIbeAwyNG");
  background-size: cover;
  padding-top:100px;
  padding-bottom:100px;
}

.icons {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0;
}
.sub_container{
  white-space:nowrap;
  display:inline-block;
  border:solid red;

}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div class="sub_container" >
  <img style="width:25%;" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTdLmT2S2vZp6WFy0hQM4vrz8W-qZyglg3973cgAhJy9a51DXahOQ">
  <h3 style="width:200px;text-align:left;font-family:Raleway;font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;text-transform:uppercase;color:#FFFFFF;">complete Project</h3>
  <h1 style="width:200px;;font-family:Arial;font-size:20px;text-transform:uppercase;color:#FFFFFF;">120</h1>
</div>
<div class="sub_container" >
 <img style="width:25%;" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTdLmT2S2vZp6WFy0hQM4vrz8W-qZyglg3973cgAhJy9a51DXahOQ">
  <h3 style="width:200px;text-align:left;font-family:Raleway;font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;text-transform:uppercase;color:#FFFFFF;">cups of coffee</h3>
  <h1 style="width:200px;font-family:Arial;font-size:20px;text-transform:uppercase;color:#FFFFFF;">570</h1>
</div>
<div class="sub_container" >
  <img style="width:25%;" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTdLmT2S2vZp6WFy0hQM4vrz8W-qZyglg3973cgAhJy9a51DXahOQ">
  <h3 style="width:200px;text-align:left;font-family:Raleway;font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;text-transform:uppercase;color:#FFFFFF;">Award Winners</h3>
  <h1 style="width:200px;font-family:Arial;font-size:20px;text-transform:uppercase;color:#FFFFFF;">682</h1>
</div>
<div class="sub_container" >
  <img style="width:25%;" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTdLmT2S2vZp6WFy0hQM4vrz8W-qZyglg3973cgAhJy9a51DXahOQ">
  <h3 style="width:200px;text-align:left;font-family:Raleway;font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;text-transform:uppercase;color:#FFFFFF;">happy customers</h3>
  <h1 style=";width:200px;;font-family:Arial;font-size:20px;text-transform:uppercase;color:#FFFFFF;">900</h1>
</div>


</div>
```

Alernative two (with a fixed height container)

```css
div {
  color: black;
}

#container {
  background: url("https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTomMW37agCBOu64_RK6Kn8kQyN9937Upm5XZXRPkwCIbeAwyNG");
  background-size: cover;
  height:500px;
}

.icons {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
}
.sub_container{
  position:relative;
  top:50%;


  white-space:nowrap;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div class="sub_container" >
  <img style="width:25%;" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTdLmT2S2vZp6WFy0hQM4vrz8W-qZyglg3973cgAhJy9a51DXahOQ">
  <h3 style="width:200px;text-align:left;font-family:Raleway;font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;text-transform:uppercase;color:#FFFFFF;">complete Project</h3>
  <h1 style="width:200px;;font-family:Arial;font-size:20px;text-transform:uppercase;color:#FFFFFF;">120</h1>
</div>
<div class="sub_container" >
 <img style="width:25%;" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTdLmT2S2vZp6WFy0hQM4vrz8W-qZyglg3973cgAhJy9a51DXahOQ">
  <h3 style="width:200px;text-align:left;font-family:Raleway;font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;text-transform:uppercase;color:#FFFFFF;">cups of coffee</h3>
  <h1 style="width:200px;font-family:Arial;font-size:20px;text-transform:uppercase;color:#FFFFFF;">570</h1>
</div>
<div class="sub_container" >
  <img style="width:25%;" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTdLmT2S2vZp6WFy0hQM4vrz8W-qZyglg3973cgAhJy9a51DXahOQ">
  <h3 style="width:200px;text-align:left;font-family:Raleway;font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;text-transform:uppercase;color:#FFFFFF;">Award Winners</h3>
  <h1 style="width:200px;font-family:Arial;font-size:20px;text-transform:uppercase;color:#FFFFFF;">682</h1>
</div>
<div class="sub_container" >
  <img style="width:25%;" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTdLmT2S2vZp6WFy0hQM4vrz8W-qZyglg3973cgAhJy9a51DXahOQ">
  <h3 style="width:200px;text-align:left;font-family:Raleway;font-weight:bold;font-size:15px;text-transform:uppercase;color:#FFFFFF;">happy customers</h3>
  <h1 style=";width:200px;;font-family:Arial;font-size:20px;text-transform:uppercase;color:#FFFFFF;">900</h1>
</div>


</div>
```

Comment: thanks but , the icons isnt on the center of the background, Please check that: http://imgh.us/Capture_554.jpg

Comment: you mean horizontally centered?

Comment: The subcontainers are centered including the icon.. I placed a border around each subcontainer in the edited answer...

Comment: I also placed another snippet where the height is fixed and you shift the containers 50% down "top:50%"..This way icons will be positioned directly half-way

Comment: still having some problems, the background moving when resizing the web browser. because that background supposed to be in the middle of the page, check out the original website that im trying to practice that: http://preview.themeforest.net/item/ultimax-onepage-html-template/full_screen_preview/19661665?_ga=1.218637851.328877626.1486953441

Comment: instead of "background-size:cover", apply a % measurement  "background-size: 100% 100%;"

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin: -17% auto;` for put class icon in center of screen

GoodLuck

Comment: that doesn't work, it placed all the icons on 0 left.